# What is the values of $a$ and $b$ without using the L'Hôpital's Rule

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose that $$\frac{(2x)^x-2} {a(x-1)+b(x-1)^2}\to 1$$ as $x \to 1$. ThenWhat is the values of $a$ and $b$ without using the L'Hôpital's Rule?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since your question isn't totally clear for me, you're asking for values of $a$ and $b$ such that the limit of your expression is $1$, right?

Comment: All right @user37238

Comment: Have you tried series expansion at $x=1$ of your expression? Or is series expansion not allowed too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $x=1+h$. Then $h\to 0$, 
$$
(2x)^x=(2+2h)^{1+h}=\mathrm{e}^{(1+h)\log (2+2h)}=\mathrm{e}^{(1+h)(\log 2+\log (1+h))}\\
=2\,\mathrm{e}^{h\log 2+(1+h)(h-h^2/2+\mathrm{O}(h^3))}=2\,\mathrm{e}^{(1+\log 2)h+h^2/2+\mathrm{O}(h^3)}\\=
2\left(1+\big((1+\log 2)h+h^2/2+\mathrm{O}(h^3)\big)+\frac{\big((1+\log 2)h+h^2/2+\mathrm{O}(h^3)\big)^2}{2}+\cdots\right) \\=2+2(1+\log 2)h+\mathcal O(h^2).
$$
So 
$$
\frac{(2x)^x-2}{x-1}=\frac{(2+2h)^{1+h}-2}{h}=2(1+\log 2)+\mathcal{O}(h)\to 2(1+\log 2).
$$
Hence $a=2(1+\log 2)$ and $b$ can have any real value.

Comment: I hope that now is correct!

Comment: Indeed - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Factor an $x-1$ out of the denominator to get $$\frac{(2x)^x-2} {a(x-1)+b(x-1)^2} = \frac{(2x)^x -  2}{x-1} \cdot \frac{1}{a + b(x-1)}$$ so that (as long as $a \not= 0$)$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{(2x)^x-2} {a(x-1)+b(x-1)^2} = \left.\frac{d}{dx} (2x)^x \right|_{x=1} \cdot \frac 1a.$$
But $\dfrac{d}{dx} (2x)^x = (2x)^x (1 + \log 2x)$, and at $x=1$ equals $2(1 + \log 2)$. Thus $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{(2x)^x-2} {a(x-1)+b(x-1)^2} = \frac{2(1 + \log 2)}{a}.$$